Finding inner product associated with an orthogonal basis
Let $S = \{1 + k_0, c_1x + k_1, c_2x^2 + k_2, c_3x(x^2 - 3) + k_3\}$ ($x(x^2 - 3)$ is so that its derivative is proportional to $(1-x)(1+x)$), $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. Is it possible to find an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ such that $S$ is an orthogonal basis of $\mathrm{span}\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$?
The constants $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ are just to allow for a rescaling depending on the choice of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, and the $k_i$ allow for a possible translation.
I tried to determine this using the Gram-Schmidt procedure applied to $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$, e.g. if $\{q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3\}$ is the orthogonal basis,
$$
q_3 = x^3 - \langle x^3, q_0 \rangle q_0 - \langle x^3, q_1 \rangle q_1 - \langle x^3, q_2 \rangle q_2,
$$
and doing this for each $q_i$ to try and solve for $\{q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3\} = \{1, c_1x, c_2x^2, c_3x(x^2 - 3)\}$, but I can't seem to find a way.
The inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = \sum_{x \in \{-1, 1\}}\sum_{i=0}^3 f^{(i)}(x)g^{(i)}(x)$ is close, but the associated $q_3$ does not match (it gives $q_0=1, q_1 = x, q_2 = x^2 - 2, q_3 = x(x^2 - 8)$).
